# Is there any anime with an overweight female protagonist?

Tags: anime-history

Is there any anime with an overweight female protagonist?

A friend of mine told me that there is none. Is she right?

I just need one simple yes/no answer and, if affirmative, one example.

Comment: Not sure if it has an anime, but Buyuden has an overweight female protagonist (though she's only overweight post timeskip)

Comment: has your friend seen every anime that was ever made?

Comment: You can look at [this query](http://www.anime-planet.com/characters/all?gender_id=2&include_tags=488&page=4) on anime-planet. That will list all overweight female characters, you will have to manually sort out which ones are side characters, and which aren't.

Comment: I vote to reopen because the wording of this question does not sound like a recommendation request. Rather, it sounds like the poster wants to know a basic fact about anime: does such a case exist?

Comment: Although it may not qualify for overweight in medical terms, the protagonist of Ghibli's 『かぐや姫の物語』 (The Tale of the Princess Kaguya) is chubbier than modern-day anime protagonists in accordance with historical fact. In 11th century Heian era, women were supposed to have round faces and ample softness (see examples in the famous novel Tale of Genji, in which Genji easily notices when women who are sick grow visibly thinner as a result of their health). Matsuko, arguably 1 of an ensemble of 5 fairly equal protagonists of Ghibli's 『ホーホケキョとなりの山田くん』 (My Neighbors the Yamadas) is clearly overweight.

Comment: @mivilar Anime-Planet now allows one to search characters by their roles, so we can easily filter out side characters: https://www.anime-planet.com/characters/all?gender_id=2&role_id=1&include_tags=488&sort=title&order=asc. The most famous example among the query result is probably Jane from Jungle King Tar-chan.

Answer (score 3):

While "overweight" can be subjective, [**Real Drive**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Drive) generated [some](http://animehomec.blogspot.com/2008/05/real-drive-hooray-for-chubby-girls.html) [buzz](https://ogiuemaniax.wordpress.com/2011/12/16/thick-with-cyberpunk-real-drive/) for chubby female characters.

The character in question is Minamo Aoi.

[image]

Sample of another female characters in the anime:

[image]

Pictures from [animecharactersdatabase](http://www.animecharactersdatabase.com/source.php?id=1503)

Comment: How can she eben be considered 'fat' …

Comment: @Jan I never called anyone "fat". As I prefaced, the term overweight is subjective unless it is used medically. The OP never specified so I gave an example of an anime that had female characters that are chubbier than the norm. This question is closed but a more recent example would be Saiko Yonebayashi from Tokyo Ghoul:Re. Not an anime yet, but given how popular the original series is, its only a matter of time. I encourage you to read the "buzz" in my answer for a better perspective.

Comment: Yeah, I understand so far. I just wanted to imply that even creating buzz about this type of characters is … overdone?

Comment: @Jan Not overdone, no. If this was a US live action show in the vein of the current superhero fad, a properly proportioned female protagonist will probably generate even more "buzz" if not outright controversy. Just look at gamer gate. Forget strong female hero, but make the protagonist a "chubby" female and all hell would break loose.